# In Correct LatLong Results from Google API response

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to understand why the resulting latlong everytime is 37.986272,-122.010576 when Firebug shows the correct coordinates are populating in targetDestination -

From Firebug:
at the point of gmaptest.html#page2 line 75>

```
targetDestination = new google.maps.LatLng(parseInt(coords[0]),parseInt(coords[1]));
```

coords- ["38.42036", "-122.662246"]

request- undefined

targetDestination- "38.42036,-122.662246"

**Here is my test page - http://legendsnorcal.dfigdesign.com/maps/gmaptest.html**

The current locaiton is pulling correctly when I initialize the second page:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#page2', function(){
var selectedDest = $('[name=latlong]').val();
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(locSuccess, locError);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not be doing a `parseInt` on geo coordinates, they are decimals.  That is probably a large part of the issue you might be having:

Try changing this to:

```
targetDestination = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(coords[0]),parseFloat(coords[1]));
```